# multiple queries in a Spark Struct Streaming job, so how to cache data?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

there are multiple queries in a spark job,  when i start this job, i found that every query start a connnect to kafka,and they don't  share data with each other,so how to cache data to avoid read same data many times.

I have tried to cache table with command "
CACHE TABLE cache_table;"
then

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:374)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:37)
org.apach
```

Comment: Please show code.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every streaming query is a separate thread. With the Kafka data source in use a streaming query is also a separate Kafka consumer.

With that said, you'd have to use them all as part of a single query so they could share data. A `join` could be a solution.